# How to navigate using button with condition check in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, navigation, swiftui-navigationlink

Since **NavigationButton** isn't available anymore, how do I check conditions in **NavigationLink** in order to navigate to another view?

```
NavigationLink(destination: Dashboard(userName: self.userId,
                                      password: self.password), isActive: $showDashboard) {
    Button(action: {
        if self.userId.isEmpty || self.password.isEmpty {
            self.isAlert = true
        } else {
            self.showDashboard = true
        }
                       
    }) {
        Text("Submit")
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .font(.system(size: 22))
                       
        Dashboard()
    }
    .frame(minWidth: 150, idealWidth: 300, maxWidth: 450,
           minHeight: 30, idealHeight: 40, maxHeight: 50, alignment: .center)
    .background(Color(red: 81/255, green: 221/255, blue: 182/255))
                       
    .padding([.leading, .trailing], 20)
}
```

**Edit:-**

Also I want to show alert if length of **userName** and **password** is more then 16 and different alert if length is more than 10 and empty message alert  if length is 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
    NavigationView {
        VStack {
            NavigationLink(destination:  Dashboard(userName: self.userId, password: self.password), isActive: $showDashboard) {
                Text("")
            }
            Button(action: {
                 if self.userId.isEmpty || self.password.isEmpty {
                      self.isAlert = true
                  } else {
                      self.showDashboard = true
                  }
            }) {
                Text("Submit")
                    .foregroundColor(.green)
                    .font(.system(size: 22))

            }
        }
    }
```

A thing to remember is that a NavigationLink is a button itself and when pressed it navigate to the `destinationView`, the `isActive` parameter is a way to force that to happen (without the user clicking the NavigationLink). As of now I'm not sure how to embed logic into NavigationLinks.

Hope this helps :)

**EDIT:**

Another thing you can do is the following:

```
NavigationLink(destination:Dashboard(userName: self.userId, password: self.password)) {
                    Text("Submit")
                }.disabled(self.userId.isEmpty || self.password.isEmpty )
```

This would disable the NavigationLink until both input fields are not empty.

Comment: i wanna show alert if condition fails. so how that is possible?

Comment: You could use `self.isAlert` to show the alert if it's true.

Comment: but where? in destination condition check?

Comment: That's outside the scope of this questions.  If this answered helped you withe the navigation accept it then you could ask about the Alert

Comment: Your code is working fine but button is only clickable at mid point. i want whole button clickable

Comment: it's working fine that was because of some button touchable area

Comment: The link only works once. If you hit back from the pushed screen, you won't be able to push again on iOS 13.3!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you want to check conditions to determine the destination of the `NavigationLink` or whether or not it is disabled, but this example code shows how to do both:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var userId = ""
    @State var password = ""

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: (self.userId.isEmpty || self.password.isEmpty) ? AnyView(Dashboard(userName: self.userId, password: self.password)) : AnyView(Text("Different view")), isActive: Binding(get: {
                return self.userId.isEmpty || self.password.isEmpty
            }, set: { (_) in

            })) {
                Text("Navigate")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Create a custom Binding for `isActive` to evaluate mulitple conditions:

```
Binding(get: {
        return self.userId.isEmpty || self.password.isEmpty
}, set: { (_) in

})
```

And evalute the conditions in a [ternary statement](https://syntaxdb.com/ref/swift/ternary), making sure to use `AnyView` for Type Erasure [to return different kinds of views](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-return-different-view-types) if you want the conditions to determine which view the `NavigationLink` navigates to:

```
(self.userId.isEmpty || self.password.isEmpty) ? AnyView(Dashboard(userName: self.userId, password: self.password) : AnyView(Text("Different view"))
```

**Edit**: You can set the other view to `nil` if you do not want the view to transition to anything if the conditional evaluates to `false`:

```
(self.userId.isEmpty || self.password.isEmpty) ? AnyView(Dashboard(userName: self.userId, password: self.password) : nil
```

**Edit 2**: If you want an alert to show up when the condition fails, use the above line (with `nil`) for the NavigationLink's destination, and add an alert who also has a custom `Binding` for `isPresented`:

```swift
.alert(isPresented: Binding(get: {
            return self.userId.isEmpty || self.password.isEmpty
    }, set: { (_) in

    })) {
        Text("Alert message")
    }
```

You can add this alert to any subview in the the view with the variables you are evaluating (in this case, `ContentView`).

Comment: i wanna show alert if condition fails. so how that is possible?

Comment: @dineshsharma check my code, I just edited it to add that info.