# How to navigate between view controllers on a button action in swiftui?

Tags: button, navigation, swiftui, viewcontroller

I want to navigate between the login screen to sign up Screen  with the help of button action.

```
   Button(action: {

                NavigationLink(destination:SignUpScene()){
                   Text("Show Detail View")
                                  }

                print("Join button tapped!!")
                   })
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to navigate using button with condition check in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58525213/how-to-navigate-using-button-with-condition-check-in-swiftui)

Comment: I just want to navigate between controllers with help of UIButton in swiftUI. One screen to another

Comment: You can define a `@State` variable, set it in NavigationLink isActive param and toggle your variable in button action

Comment: @Mac3n, I am new in swiftUI field can you show me any demo of navigation between controllers with help of button action?

Comment: what type of navigation you need ? present a screen or navigate using push action ?

Comment: @Mac3n navigate using push action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create navigation link and set properties to show it like button:
Here is my code:

```
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {

            //Button to navigate to another page
            NavigationLink(destination: AlertView()) {
                Text("GO TO ALERT")
                    .padding(15)
                    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .background(Color.red)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    .cornerRadius(4)
            }
            .padding([.leading, .trailing], 30)
            .padding([.top], 21)
            .frame(height: 50)
        }
    }
```

Here is how it looks:

[image]

Hope it helps..Good Luck :)